# Start up script to re-start the NodeJS app is not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use the startup-script meta to automatically start my server when my instance resets.

The startup script runs, but the actual command I need doesn't work. What am I doing wrong in this script?

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "testing" > /tmp/test-script.txt # This WORKS
cd /../ && npm start # This does NOT work
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your package.json file, it says `"start": "command"` and that is the command that is run when you use the `npm start` command. The command should be changed in package.json: `"start": "node ./pathToStartUpScripts"`. For example in an Express.js project the start command would be `"node ./bin/www"` as that is where all the application start up scripts are written.

Comment: Ok, then could you explain why the startup script is ignored when I write "pm2 resurrect" ?